# Call load() from react-howler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, howler.js

I want to call load() with set timeout ,how add to my code

It offer from library

Docs:

> load()

> When preload is true this is automatically called. When setting
> preload to false, you can call load() manually before playing sounds
> (useful for lazy loading large files on slow networks). If you attempt
> to play a sound that's not loading or loaded with preload react-howler
> will automatically call load().

And there is my code

```
  <ReactHowler
          src={Audio}
          preload={false}
          playing={isplaying ? false : true}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

For a fully controlled example (in a class-based component) take a look at [the official examples](https://github.com/thangngoc89/react-howler/blob/master/examples/react/src/players/FullControl.js)

The trick is to get a `ref` to the howler component, then you can call load on it. So the following should work:

```
const howlerRef = useRef(null);

const myLoadFunc = ()=>{
  if(howlerRef.current) {
    howlerRef.current.load();
  }
}

return (
  <>
    <ReactHowler
          src={Audio}
          preload={false}
          playing={isplaying ? false : true}
          ref={howlerRef}
        />
    <button onClick={myLoadFunc}>start loading</button>
  </>
)
```